# How to remember scrolled position of UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

In Safari, when you

1. Visit a very long page, e.g. w3c.org, scroll down to somewhere in the page
2. Kill Safari
3. Open Safari again, it will automatically remember your last position within a page

How to do this in `UIWebView`? Or is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of to achieve this would be to save the web views `contentOffset.y` and then set it back to what you saved the next time it is loaded.

Saving this into `NSUserDefaults` will allow the value to be restored even if the app is killed, or even if an update is installed.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:myWebView.scrollView.contentOffset.y forKey:@"offsetKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Then to restore:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [myWebView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"offsetKey"]) animated:YES];
}
```

^^Untested, let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Make sure you wait until the content is fully loaded (webView delegate) before attempting this.